# Operation timed out: installing and running app

Tags: simulator, firefox-os

I'm getting the following error message when I try different operations such as installing an application to a Firefox OS simulator:

`Operation timed out: installing and running app`

I've tried versions 1.3, 1.4, 2.0 of the simulator - all have the same error.

The application does get deployed to the simulator and runs. However, `console.log()` output does not get displayed in the WebIDE Console.

For the location of the error message, see the screenshot below

[image]

My Firefox Version is - 42.0a1 (2015-07-16)

This is running on Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

When I click on the [Troubleshooting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/WebIDE/Troubleshooting) link, I can't find any tips for troubleshooting a simulator.

Any ideas?

---

The steps I followed were:

1. Open WebIDE.  Terminal output:

`* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
 * daemon started successfully *`

2. Start Firefox OS 2.0 simulator, simulator displays.  Terminal output:

`console.log: Connection status changed: connecting
 console.log: Connection status changed: connected`

3. Project >> Open Packaged App, and select my application. No Terminal output.
4. Project >> Install and Run.  Application displays on simulator.  Terminal output:

`console.log: Installing app from /home/snowch/tmp/Scratch/myapp/hw_chs
 console.log: Starting bulk upload
 console.log: File size: 14253
 console.log: Bulk upload done`

5. After about 10 seconds the error message is shown as per the screenshot.

---

Update

The jconsole error messages:

1. Simulating large screen devices (Operation timed out: installing and running app)

[image]

2. Simulating small screen devices, after clicking on the spanner (Operation timed out: opening toolbox)

[image]

Comment: Can you describe your steps more precisely? First, you connect to a runtime? Then you press the play button to install the app, or something else? Does the toolbox open at all?

Comment: @jryans - I've added the steps to the question.

Comment: It appears that the problem was because I was simulating the Via Vixen.  After restoring the defaults, the above error message goes away, but is replaced by 'Operation timed out: opening toolbox'

Comment: @jryans it seems that the error 'Operation timed out: installing and running app' only happens when simulating devices with larger screens.

Comment: Okay, so you never see a toolbox (inspector, etc.) appear at all? Can you check the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) to see if it includes any more detail?

Comment: I've updated the question with the jsconsole output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've run into several bugs with older simulator versions.

For the issue with app install when the screen is set to Via Vixen, I filed [bug 1186929](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1186929).  For myself, it only reproduced on 2.0, but please comment in that bug if you have more specifics.

For the "opening toolbox" issue, I believe that is a compatibility problem that needs to be resolved with older simulators, which is [bug 1161131](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1161131).

I tried asking several times in the comments above if you ever actually see the toolbox appear, or if you just get error messages.  It would still help to know the answer here.

As a workaround, you should be able to use Simulator 2.2 or later to avoid these issues until they are resolved.

Comment: 2.2 works great - thanks!  Yes the toolbox did open for me after encountering the above errors.  Apologies for not responding to your question before.